# Seatpost mounted luggage rack on carbon frame

Tags: carbon, rack, panniers

Planning on taking my carbon Ribble to Wales to go play in the valleys.  Need to carry limited luggage from point to point.  Looking at a seatpost mounted rack like the Topeak RX beam, but wanted thoughts on whether this is a good idea on a carbon bike?  Have an alloy seat post but don't want to damage the carbon seat tube.

Comment: Maybe the answers to this question can point you in the right direction: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/37874/47354

Comment: How much post do you have inserted into the frame?. if it is manufacturer minimum, and you are a Clydesdale, then probably pushing some design limits.  If you are a light weight and have a lot seat post inserted, it should be fine.

Answer (score 6):

For the sake of argument, let's suppose you weigh 70 kg, and 60% of your weight is being carried directly over the seatpost (the rest being on your hands). Let's further suppose that you have 10 kg of gear cantilevered out behind the seatpost, with its center of mass being 30 cm away.

In terms of what the frame "sees," the seatpost rack would move your combined center of mass backward by 58 mm. This would be about the same as if you started with your seat fully forward on the rails, and moved it fully rearward and carried the additional load on your back. My guess is the frame can handle that kind of loading.